# Ask E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin

#kotlin
i have a problem "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"
How do i fixed it ?

> My [fragment](https://pastebin.com/AKpUxXd6)`

```
 override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
            rvMovie = view.findViewById(R.id.homefragment)
            list.addAll(MovieData.listData)
            showRecyclerMovie1()
            return view
        }
```

> My [adapter](https://pastebin.com/hm11FFAW)

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardViewViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_cardview_movie,
            viewGroup,
            false
        )
        return CardViewViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: we aren't going to click on those links here, please add enough (relevant) code for others to help. remember, this isn't a debugging service, we're here to help other with similar problems in future as well

Comment: Please attach code instead link.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you have to add an adapter to your rv.

```
val adapter = MyAdapter();
rv.adapter = adapter
```

since this is a very basic question, i recommend anyone that show's up here to go a watch an android dev tutorial.